# PHP and MySQL - Unable to correctly assign an object's field value from a query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, class

This is a bit of a tricky one, and may seem lengthy but it's all small snippets of code and a fairly "simple" issue. Really need help with this one (and I'm NOT allowed to use PDO or any other database handler method other than this one, as defined by the school):

I have this class (abridged with relevant fields only)

```
class Publication {

    public $num_author;
    public $author;

    public function __construct(..., $set_num_author) {
        $this->num_author = $set_num_author;
    }

    public function setAuthor($set_author) {
        $this->author = $set_author;
    }

    public function getNumAuthor() {
        return $this->num_author;
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to set its Author field. To do so, I need to use the numAuthor value for a query (Author's name and its number are in different tables), namely:

```
 "SELECT title, abstract, body, DATE_FORMAT(date, '%d-%m-%Y'), type, updated_user_id FROM publication WHERE type = 0 and enabled = 1 ORDER BY created_at DESC";
  //gets me the author id

 "SELECT name FROM person WHERE id = ?";
 //...which I then use to get the author's name
```

I instance the publications like so:

```
  $stmt_pubs_medicos->bind_result($title, $abstract, $body, $date, $type, $num_author);
    while ($stmt_pubs_medicos->fetch()) {
            $pub = new model\Publication($title, $abstract, $body, $date, $type, $num_author);
            array_push($latest_publications, $pub);
        }
  }
```

And I save them into latest_publications array as I expect to only get the 3 first (only showing the first, I unrolled the loop):

```
  $stmt_author->bind_param('i', $pub->getNumAuthor());
  $stmt_author->bind_result($author_name);
  $stmt_author->fetch();
  $latest_publications[0]->setAuthor($author_name);
```

But there's a problem. Once I show the publications in the webpage's div, although the body and date of each publication is different, as it should be, the author is the same. Namely the one from the 2nd latest publication ($latest_publications[1]). Why does this happen?

EDIT:

```
$stmt_autor = $db->conn->prepare($query_autor);
        $stmt_autor->bind_param('i', $latest_publications[0]->getNumAuthor());
        $stmt_autor->bind_result($nome_autor);
        $stmt_autor->fetch();
       $latest_publications[0]->setAuthor($nome_autor);

        $stmt_autor = $db->conn->prepare($query_autor);
        $stmt_autor->bind_param('i', $latest_publications[1]->getNumAuthor());
        $stmt_autor->bind_result($nome_autor);
        $stmt_autor->fetch();
      $latest_publications[1]->setAuthor($nome_autor);

        $stmt_autor = $db->conn->prepare($query_autor);
        $stmt_autor->bind_param('i', $latest_publications[2]->getNumAuthor());
        $stmt_autor->bind_result($nome_autor);
        $stmt_autor->fetch();
        $latest_publications[2]->setAuthor($nome_autor);
```

Comment: not sure if this is relevant - but i think i see a typo here `$pub = new model\Publication($title, $abstract, $body, $date, $type, $num_autor);` - `$num_autor` should be `$num_author` right?

Comment: also in this line `$stmt_pubs_medicos->bind_result($title, $abstract, $body, $date, $type, $num_autor);`

Comment: i dont know why that would cause the same author to be displayed...but computers can be weird :)

Comment: It was translated from portuguese, forgot to change those. Editing ^^

Comment: Maybe you'd want to use the function `var_dump()` to monitor your vars until you find the bit that's causing the issue. This is most likely a design-related problem. You may also [want to take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make your code easier to understand, it's hard to make some guesses, we're not the ones developing the application.

Comment: I can't use PDO, only this Database handler, I need a fix for this code as is

Comment: I could post links to the files in question?

Comment: `var_dump()` is NOT PDO. And are you trying to say that the name is duplicated from the 2 index (index 1) and onwards?

Comment: It looks like you're only calling `$stmt_author->fetch();` once, that is only getting the first record. Is that what you want? Or am I missing something.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles thats inside a loop, according to the OP, so it's called for every record. OP, can you show the complete structure of the loop around `$latest_publications[0]->setAuthor($author_name);` ??

Comment: The code is as it is in the dit, I unrolled the loop, since I thought the problem was me using a counter variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

real OP here.
I had my friend post this question in my behalf since my school IP blocked me. So it was hard to get back with proper feedback or in time. I finally cracked the issue:

After unrolling, I ommitted the `$stmt_autor->execute();` call and before that I was calling it **BEFORE** `$stmt_autor->bind_params();`
Hence the NULL/Empty Author name field. Snippet of the final, clean working code, portion of the loop:

```
$stmt_autor_med = $db->conn->prepare($query_autor);
    if (!$stmt_autor_med) {
        $code = $db->conn->errno;
        $message = $db->conn->error;
        printf("<p>SQL Error: %d %s</p>", $code, $message);
    }
    $stmt_autor_med->bind_param('i', $numeros_dos_autores[0]);
    $stmt_autor_med->bind_result($nome_m);
    if (!$stmt_autor_med->execute()) {
        $code = $stmt_autor_med->errno;
        $message = $stmt_autor_med->error;
        printf("<p>Execution error: %d %s</p>", $code, $message);
    } else {

        $stmt_autor_med->fetch();
        $ultimas_publicacoes_medicos[0]->autor = $nome_m;
    }
    $stmt_autor_med->free_result();
    $stmt_autor_med->close();
```

Variable names are in portuguese, but you'll get the jist. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you better start using PHP's `PDO` rather than the `mysql` extensions, it'll save you a lot of trouble, and syntax and error handling are cleaner:

Example:

```
$DBH = new PDO('mysql:host=http://yourhost.com;dbname=yourdbname;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
$DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$STH = $DBH->prepare('SELECT * FROM `yourtable` WHERE `yourcolumn` = ?');
$STH->bindParam(1, $yourparam);
$STH->execute();

$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$mydata = array();
while ($var = $STH->fetch()) {
    /* Retrieve the information */
    $mydata[] = $var;
}

$DBH = null;
```

The `fetch()` method will return an anonymous object (because of `setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)`) and its field names will be set to that of your columns' names. E.g:

If your table has the columns:

```
id, name, date, address
```

Your object will have the fields, with the corresponding information of the query:

```
$obj->id
$obj->name
$obj->date
$obj->address
```

You can find more information on [**phpro.org's PDO tutorial pages**](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html). They are pretty well explained.

Comment: That is not an option, this is for a school project and I'm obliged to use this database handling method...

Comment: As long as it's not a production environment, I think you're free to present a (much better) solution to the given problem (specially if this is school related stuff), but anyway, the suggestion will still be here in case you change yur mind.